# Implementation of BERT in keras with TF_HUB

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, tf.keras

I was trying to implement the Google Bert model in tensorflow-keras using tensorflow hub. For this I designed a custom keras layer "Bertlayer" . Now the problem is when I am compiling the keras model it keeps showing that

AttributeError: 'Bertlayer' object has no attribute '_keras_style'

I don't know where I am wrong and what _keras_style attribute is.Please help to find the error in the code.

This is the github link to the full code: https://github.com/PradyumnaGupta/BERT/blob/master/Untitled21.ipynb

```py
class BertLayer(tf.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_fine_tune_layers=10, **kwargs):
        self.n_fine_tune_layers = n_fine_tune_layers
        self.trainable = True
        self.output_size = 768
        super(BertLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.bert = hub.Module(
            bert_path,
            trainable=self.trainable,
            name="{}_module".format(self.name)
        )

        trainable_vars = self.bert.variables

        # Remove unused layers
        trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars if not "/cls/" in var.name]

        # Select how many layers to fine tune
        trainable_vars = trainable_vars[-self.n_fine_tune_layers :]

        # Add to trainable weights
        for var in trainable_vars:
            self._trainable_weights.append(var)

        for var in self.bert.variables:
            if var not in self._trainable_weights:
                self._non_trainable_weights.append(var)

        super(BertLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs = [K.cast(x, dtype="int32") for x in inputs]
        input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids = inputs
        bert_inputs = dict(
            input_ids=input_ids, input_mask=input_mask, segment_ids=segment_ids
        )
        result = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
            "pooled_output"
        ]
        return result

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_size)
```

Comment: excuse me i'm using same code but got NameError: name 'bert_path' is not defined

Comment: You need to declare a global variable bert_path which contains the path. You can get the path from hub.

Answer (score 0):

So, tensorflow version 1.* is a bit misleading. It actually has 2 bases classes called Layer. One - the one that you are using. It is intended to implement shortcut wrappers over regular TF operations. The other `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer` is for Keras-like models and sequencies.

Judging by your error, you are using keras/models to train further.

You probably should start form derivering your layer from `keras.layers.Layer` instead of `tf.layers.Layer`.

Comment: Thank you so very much ....that just solved my problem !!Sorry for the late reply though !!!